# Как открыть/протестировать страницу localhost в Safari/Ios8 и Andriod5 (эмуляторы)

Tags: android, вёрстка, localhost, ios8, эмулятор

Есть сайт в среде Node.js (npm) - localhost:3000

Искал безплатные локальные эмуляторы Safari/Ios8 и Andriod5, но безрезультатно. Плагинов для браузеров также не нашел, о одном браузер предупредил, что небезопасный.

Есть ли проверенные способы это сделать, открыть/протестировать страницу localhost в Safari/Ios8 и Andriod5 локально?

Не рассматриваю варианты открытия портов на роутере и т.п.

Comment: Проблема - надуманная. Зачем локалхост - загрузите на VPS и зачеркните слово "локальный". И тестируйте, например, на browserstack. Еще есть несколько сервисов, дающих VPS именно с OS X - там симулятор iOS запустите - а в нем Safari. А насчет Android 5 - здесь Genymotion рулит, и вот у него есть бесплатная версия - ищите лучше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://appetize.io/ - **лучший выбор!** Со временем, можно и оплатить.

https://www.browserstack.com/ - платный, большой выбор устройств и версий брайзеров.